# How to convert a single vertex into a plane within a mesh?

Tags: modeling, vertices

I've seen two different videos where the user selected a single vertex and then expanded it into a 4 sided plane. This is a technique I've needed many times but I am not sure how that was accomplished.

This picture sort of demonstrates what I'm trying to reproduce. 
before (left) and after (right)
[image: example topology]

Comment: Could you provide a link to a video you saw it in

Comment: @IgorTatarnikov I spent quite a while this afternoon looking for it but cannot find it. If I do I'll provide that link.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Select the vertex and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>B</kbd> that will [bevel](https://www.blender.org/manual/modeling/meshes/editing/subdividing/bevel.html) the vertex, creating a new face.
Do note that doing so will create Ngons in the surrounding faces.

[image: animated gif]

Comment: perhaps I should clarify. I'm wanting to add an extra quad inside a grid (example) of existing quads by turning a single vertex into a quad of its own.

Comment: @David another cool shotcut I haven't heard about before! Better and faster than TLousky's solution. +1 from me. P.s. Frankly, you were the first person here, who found out the right solution.

Answer (score 11):

From the screenshot in your question, it seems like you're trying to convert a vertex inside an existing mesh into a quad face, rather than creating a plane from a single vertex.

This can be achieved with the bevel tool (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd>), as seen in this image:

[image]

Comment: YES! this is precisely what I was trying to do.